# trying to get my input values rounded off to next two decimals

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, tofixed

Hi please help I am trying to get toFixed(2) don't know where I am going wrong

```
function addFunction(item) {
            let cost = 0
            if (totalSettings < criticalLevel) {
                switch (item) {
                    case "call":
                        cost = callCost.toFixed(2);
                        totalSettings += callCost;
                        callTotalSettings += callCost;
                        break;
                    case "sms":
                        cost = smsCost.toFixed(2);
                        totalSettings += smsCost;
                        smsTotalSettings += smsCost;
                        break;
                }
                userMappedData.push({
                    type: item,
                    cost,
                    timestamp: new Date()
                })
                return true
            }
        }
```

```
function settingsBillTotals() {
            return {
                totalSettings.toFixed(2),
                callTotalSettings.toFixed(2),
                smsTotalSettings.toFixed(2)
            };
        }
```

please note settingsBillTotals() currently doesnt work thats where i thought i should put toFixed()
i tried putting it on total settings but still wont work, my heroku app link https://settingsbillexpress.herokuapp.com/ if not sure what i mean

Comment: How are you getting totalSettings and other values? Try using parseFloat then use toFixed

Comment: they are all global variables
```
// variables
        var callTotalSettings = null;
        var smsTotalSettings = null;
        var totalSettings = null;
        var callCost;
        var smsCost;
        var warningLevel;
        var criticalLevel;
        var userMappedData = [];
```
i'll just read about parsefloat + toFixed as i have never done it before

Comment: put a console.log in your settingsBillTotals function to make sure its actually called before updating UI

Comment: it currently works please look at https://settingsbillexpress.herokuapp.com/

the problem i have is knowing exactly knowing where to put the toFixed(), id really appreciate if you look at the app response to see what i mean https://settingsbillexpress.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

````
let totalset = totalSettings.toFixed(2);
let callTotalset = callTotalSettings.toFixed(2);
let smsTotalset = smsTotalSettings.toFixed(2);
return {
    totalset,
    callTotalset,
    smsTotalset
        };
}```
````